# Windows 10 IOT UWF Unified Write Filter implementation powershell applyupdate is not recognized as the name of cmdlet

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, windows-10-iot-core

I was trying to implement windows 10 iot Unified Write Filter implementation.

I wanted to run these commands to remote iot device through powershell.
    change to the directory where you have copied your files
        cd C:\UWFTemp
    commands to install the packages to your IoT device system image:
        applyupdate –stage .\Microsoft-IoTUAP-UnifiedWriteFilter-Package.cab
        applyupdate –stage .\Microsoft-IoTUAP-UnifiedWriteFilter-Package_Lang_en-us.cab
        applyupdate –commit

And I'm getting error as

```
PS C:\UWFTemp> applyupdate -stage Microsoft-IoTUAP-UnifiedWriteFilter-Package.cab

The term 'applyupdate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (applyupdate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The file which I'm running this command exists and working fine. I'm new to shell scripting, I couldn't find how to install package for get running the applyupdate command.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not accessed the remote device via Powershell. Please try to copy the packages into your device and connect the remote device via Powershell. This document shows how to use UWF on Windows 10 IoT Core(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/secure-your-device/unifiedwritefilter).

Comment: I did connect through powershell as shown in the document the development pc doesn't recognize this command. I tried from many Windows 10 enterprise pc. I found an alternative of applyupdate command which is Add-WindowsPackage -Online -PackagePath .\Microsoft-IoTUAP-UnifiedWriteFilter-Package.cab. It did the job for now.

Comment: @Matthew, yes, Add-WindowsPackage can work also. applyupdate works for me. Which version of Windows IoT Core are you using? Is it a custom OS? I